# When to validate/sanitize the arguments of an overridden method?

Tags: php, validation, oop, sanitization, overriding

What can you tell about validating/sanitizing the arguments of a overridden method in a class?

If I have something like

```
class parentClass
{
    public function originalMethod($id) {
        if(is_numeric($id) && (int) $id > 0) {
            // use $id
        }
    }
}
```

and a subclass that overrides the method

```
class childClass extends parentClass
{
    public function originalMethod($id) {

        parent::originalMethod($id);

        // do other stuff 
    }
}
```

My question is:

***in which cases would you proceed with a validation of the method's arguments?***

Shouldn't I expect/assume that the right validation has already performed in the parent method?

I've seen sometime code where the validation is performed again (not in a simple case like the one above).

Would you validate each time? Never? Just under some circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use as general guide line:

- If the base function is called in the overridden function as first statement, the verification is 
  done already in the overridden function. In some cases additional verifications need to be added in the overridden function. Unless the base function changes the variables used for verification which are used in the overridden function.
- If the base function is not called, you have to think about the verification; normally it needs to be copied, sometimes extended or deleted (partly).
- If the base function is called after the overridden function (or not in the beginning), some verification might be needed; the other verifiction will be handled in the base function.

Of course these is just a guideline; exceptions can occur.

Answer (score 1):

In the case above you *must* revalidate, because the parent does not abort the execution of your code if the input is not valid. It just encapsulates its own code.

In other cases where you have control over the parent function and you can be sure, that it does save your overwritten function from invalid input you can skip the test.

Generally speaking I would reevaluate, just to be on the save side. If this becomes a performance concern later on, you can rethink this approach case by case.